# DirectShow Jerky Video Playback at Speed

Tags: c#, directshow

I am using DirectShow/VMR9 to playback a MPEG 4 video in my application. I use IMediaSeeking SetRate to set the speed of the video. Playing back a video I have created plays well at speeds up to 4x, above this the video becomes very jerky. Playing back the same file using Windows media player at speeds above 4x is not jerky. Can anyone shed some light as to why windows media player can play my file OK at speed but my DirectShow filter graph cannot.

My graph topology is Recording.avi -> AVI Splitter -> Mpeg4s Decoder DMO -> Ds.NET Grabber -> Color Space Converter -> Video Mixing Renderer 9.

Please let me know if you need any further information.

**Update**

I removed the grabber (and thus csc as well) and playback is not jerky up to 8x which would be good enough but I do need the grabber. The CSC ended up there when I added the grabber. I would like if possible to remove the CSC to see if that improves things while retaining the grabber. Below are my graphs with intermediate formats with and without the filter. I tried setting the media subtype of the grabber to NV12 (like the non grabber graph), however I get error a "No combination of intermediate filters could be found to make the connection." I include my code for configuring the grabber.

Is it possible to get this to work without the csc?

Also not sure if it is relevant but I do not understand how the video dimensions are changed on the graph without grabber.

**With Grabber**

Recording.avi ----- (AVI) ----- AVI Splitter ----- (MP4V - 704*576 – 24bits ) ----- Mpeg4s Decoder DMO ----- (RGB24 704*576) ----- Ds.NET Grabber - (RGB24 704*576) ----- Color Space Converter ----- (ARGB32 704*576) ----- Video Mixing Renderer 9

**Without Grabber**

Recording.avi ----- (AVI) ----- AVI Splitter  ----- (MP4V - 704*576 – 24bits ) ----- Mpeg4s Decoder DMO ----- (NV12 768*576 12 bits) ----- Video Mixing Renderer 9.

```
 private void ConfigureSampleGrabber(ISampleGrabber sampleGrabber)
 {
        AMMediaType media;
        int hr;

        // Set the media type to Video/RBG24
        media = new AMMediaType();
        media.majorType = MediaType.Video;
        media.subType = MediaSubType.ARGB32; // tried NV12 here, gives error.
        media.formatType = FormatType.VideoInfo;
        hr = sampleGrabber.SetMediaType(media);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        DsUtils.FreeAMMediaType(media);
        media = null;

        // Configure the samplegrabber
        hr = sampleGrabber.SetBufferSamples(true);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
    }
```

***CPU Usage details***

**Core i3 - 3300MHz – with hyperthreading 4GB RAM**

*4x Speed*

CPU1 ~45%

CPU2 ~0%

CPU3 ~33%

CPU4 ~0%

*8x Speed*

CPU1 ~40%

CPU2 ~25% (but very spiky 0-50%)

CPU3 ~40%

CPU4 ~0%

**Core i3 - 3300MHz – Hyperthreading disabled in BIOS.**

*4x Speed*

CPU1 ~45%

CPU2 ~33%

*8x Speed (same results at 16x Speed)*

CPU1 ~66%

CPU2 ~45%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical cause would be that at this playback rate your decoding thread is running at 100% CPU and is not capable to decode more frames, you start seeing irregular frame presentation and/or frames dropped.

Where to look:

- check your CPU with task manager or another application to see if one of the cores is maxed out and is no longer going to idle state
- checked VMR properties to see if frames are dropped, or jitter is getting too high

[image]

Comment: CPU load is not too high and I start to see jitter and frames dropped when playing back at high speed. Removing the grabber does seem to improve things.

Comment: The grabber and the `CSC` filters are not the problem themselves - their overhead is minimal (another answer states opposite, but it is not quite correct). The problem you are having with adding grabber is that decoder is forced to output `RGB` video as opposed to nicely formatted `NV12`. `RGB` conversion adds overhead, and consumes more hardware bandwidth - this is the performance hit. But this is exactly what you set your pipeline to do as you want to copy `RGB` data from your grabber into application. Anyhow, I still suspect that the bottleneck is CPU and/or your grabber callback.

Comment: I have added CPU usage details to my original post I don't consider them excessively high? Also regarding your comment on the callback I am not using one I am buffering the frames `sampleGrabber.SetBufferSamples(true);` and then using `sampleGrabber.GetCurrentBuffer(xx,xx)` whenever the capture image button is pressed.

Comment: Buffering is expensive operation - you keep copying every video frame into a buffer regardless from whether you actually need it or not. This is even worse then callback in terms of performance, because in the callback you might be just keeping a reference of media sample without touching data before it is actually required.

Comment: While trying to resolve a different issue regarding Ctl+Alt+Del and freezing video I installed K-Lite codec pack and disabled Mpeg4s Decoder DMO and ffshow video filter, this forced the graph to use AVI Decompressor as the decoder. On doing this my video plays very well up to 16x speed. I understand what you are saying about the buffer and if I have time I will have a go at this as well.

Answer (score 1):

For the playback of videos the MediaPlayer is using MediaFoundation. And for most videos the playback is hardware accelerated. If you have some filters between the decoder and the renderer in DirectShow, there is no hardware acceleration in DirectShow.
Try it again without the DS.Net Grabber and the color-space-converter (=> csc is also a huge performance killer)

Comment: Removing the grabber removes the jerkyness though I do need the grabber. I am trying to remove the csc if possible, please see updated my updates first post.